# Node JS error "cannot GET": won't pass search query to function

Tags: node.js, express, twitter-streaming-api

I am attempting to build a basic twitter sentiment analysis application using node, express, twit, and sentiment. It will let the user enter a search term, and the code below will return a sentiment analysis as long as the stream is open. However, when I enter a search term, such as "music", I get the error:
**Cannot GET /monitor?phrase=music**
I am not sure where the code is going wrong, but I imagine that *monitoringPhrase* is not being assigned correctly or the query isn't being stored. Ignore 'sentimentImage', I didn't include the code because it isn't relevant.

```
  app.get('/',
        function (req, res) {
            var welcomeResponse = "<HEAD>" +
                "<title>Twitter Sentiment Analysis</title>\n" +
                "</HEAD>\n" +
                "<BODY>\n" +
                "<P>\n" +
                "Welcome to the Twitter Sentiment Analysis app.<br>\n" + 
                "What would you like to monitor?\n" +
                "</P>\n" +
                "<FORM action=\"/monitor\" method=\"get\">\n" +
                "<P>\n" +
                "<INPUT type=\"text\" name=\"phrase\"><br><br>\n" +
                "<INPUT type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\">\n" +
                "</P>\n" + "</FORM>\n" + "</BODY>";
            if (!monitoringPhrase) {
                res.send(welcomeResponse);
            } else {
                var monitoringResponse = "<HEAD>" +
                    "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5; URL=http://" +
                    req.headers.host +
                    "/\">\n" +
                    "<title>Twitter Sentiment Analysis</title>\n" +
                    "</HEAD>\n" +
                    "<BODY>\n" +
                    "<P>\n" +
                    "The Twittersphere is feeling<br>\n" +
                    "<IMG align=\"middle\" src=\"" + sentimentImage() + "\"/><br>\n" +
                    "about " + monitoringPhrase + ".<br><br>" +
                    "Analyzed " + tweetCount + " tweets...<br>" +
                    "</P>\n" +
                    "<A href=\"/reset\">Monitor another phrase</A>\n" +
                    "</BODY>";
                res.send(monitoringResponse);
            }
        });

    var tweetCount = 0;
    var tweetTotalSentiment = 0;
    var monitoringPhrase;

    function resetMonitoring() {
        monitoringPhrase = "";
    }

    function beginMonitoring(phrase) {
        var stream;
        // cleanup if we're re-setting the monitoring
        if (monitoringPhrase) {
            resetMonitoring();
        }
        monitoringPhrase = phrase;
        tweetCount = 0;
        tweetTotalSentiment = 0;

                stream = tweeter.stream('statuses/filter', {
                    'track': monitoringPhrase
                }, function (stream) {
                    console.log("Monitoring Twitter for " + monitoringPhrase);
                    stream.on('data', function (data) {
                        // only evaluate the sentiment of English-language tweets
                        if (data.lang === 'en') {
                            sentiment(data.text, function (err, result) {
                                tweetCount++;
                                tweetTotalSentiment += result.score;
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
                return stream;

        };
```

Comment: What other error do you see with "Cannot GET", if any?

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have an `app.get('/monitor', function(){})` route defined.
Also, I can't see `beginMonitoring` being called anywhere.

This is a bit of a long shot, but I think you want something more like this:

```
var welcomeResponse = "<HEAD>" +
    "<title>Twitter Sentiment Analysis</title>\n" +
    "</HEAD>\n" +
    "<BODY>\n" +
    "<P>\n" +
    "Welcome to the Twitter Sentiment Analysis app.<br>\n" + 
    "What would you like to monitor?\n" +
    "</P>\n" +
    "<FORM action=\"/monitor\" method=\"get\">\n" +
    "<P>\n" +
    "<INPUT type=\"text\" name=\"phrase\"><br><br>\n" +
    "<INPUT type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\">\n" +
    "</P>\n" + "</FORM>\n" + "</BODY>";
var tweetCount = 0;
var tweetTotalSentiment = 0;
var monitoringPhrase = "";

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.send(welcomeResponse);
});

app.get('/monitor', function (req, res) {
    if ('phrase' in req.query && req.query.phrase != "" && req.query.phrase != monitoringPhrase) {
        // Picked new phrase to monitor
        beginMonitoring(req.query.phrase);
    }
    if (monitoringPhrase) {
        // Keep monitoring current phrase
        var monitoringResponse = "<HEAD>" +
            "<META http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"5; URL=http://" +
            req.headers.host +
            "/\">\n" +
            "<title>Twitter Sentiment Analysis</title>\n" +
            "</HEAD>\n" +
            "<BODY>\n" +
            "<P>\n" +
            "The Twittersphere is feeling<br>\n" +
            "<IMG align=\"middle\" src=\"" + sentimentImage() + "\"/><br>\n" +
            "about " + monitoringPhrase + ".<br><br>" +
            "Analyzed " + tweetCount + " tweets...<br>" +
            "</P>\n" +
            "<A href=\"/reset\">Monitor another phrase</A>\n" +
            "</BODY>";
        res.send(monitoringResponse);
    } else {
        // No phrase chosen, so just show the default page.
        res.send(welcomeResponse)
    }
});
```

Comment: It works!..sort of. I can now search a term, however the image does not render, the tweet count remains at zero forever, and it refreshes ever 5 seconds or so. If I click the link to "monitor another phrase", it says cannot GET /reset

Comment: I'm not sure why all that doesn't render, are you sure you're sending that information to the client? Also, you need another app.get function for the '/reset' route.